# The name and intuition as well for this type of equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am not a person who has expertise in partial differential equations, but I wish to gain an abstract-level intuition of a potentially very well-known equation written below at (3). For a starter, I am at least familiar with the heat equation

(1) ${\partial_{t}u = \Delta u}$,

for which the fundamental solution is known as the isotropic Gaussian kernel that performs a lowpass filter on the function ${u}$. The equation above is also termed a "forward diffusion", and negating the sign

(2) ${\partial_{t}u = -\Delta u}$

instead sharpens the function ${u}$ in contrast to the forward diffusion, thereby called a backward diffusion. I hope this presentation is not absolutely wrong. Now, my question is the equation of the form

(3) ${\partial_{t}u = -\|D u\|_{2}^{2}}$.

My expectation is that this equation (3) results in a similar behavior to (2). Could you please let me know the name and **what the intuition is**, similar to the (backward) heat diffusion? What would be the most important difference in terms of behavior?

The symbol ${\Delta}$ denotes the Laplace operator that sums up the second-order derivative along each dimension of the function ${u}$ in space, and the symbol ${D}$ denotes the differential operator, although I prefer to perceive it as just ${\nabla}$ for a differentiable function ${u}$. The symbol ${t}$ denotes time.

I think

(4) ${\partial_{t}u = +\|D u\|_{2}^{2}}$

is what we call the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, although I have zero intuition in terms of behavior. Most of the scientific articles throw me a ton of mathematical properties or solution approaches but not intuitions for a person outside the realm of partial differential equations.

**Update 1.** It appears very challenging to develop "a general intuition" for equation (3, 4). Then, what could be realworld examples, e.g., physical phenomena, for equation (3)?

Comment: Changing the sign of $\partial_t u$ in an equation (without any other mention of $t$) corresponds to reversing the direction of time, i.e.  $U(x,t)$ is a solution of the first equation iff $U(x,-t)$ is a solution of the second.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is where I got stuck. Equation (4) is the Hamilton-Jacobi equation as far as I believe, but since I do not have an intuition for (4), there is no hope of understanding (3).

Comment: They aren't general solutions, but the solutions of $\partial_t u = \pm \left( (\partial_{x_1} u)^2 +  \ldots +(\partial_{x_n} u)^2\right)$ include
$u = a + c_0 t + c_1 x_1 + \ldots + c_n x_n$ where $c_0 = \pm (c_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2)$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Interesting. What do we mean by "general solution" compared to your example? Could you also give me the intution of your example solution? It appears that your example solution is a fully linear equation both in time and space with a constant bias ${a}$. Could you attempt to connect to an intuition like heat diffusion?

Comment: (1) [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) the heat equation and not the Laplace equation. A good book that also gives some intuition should be the one by Olver.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the correction. I appreciate that too.

Comment: The main difference between the pair (1),(2) and (3),(4) is that the former are linear equations, while the latter are non linear: i.e. when $u,v$ are solutions then a linear combination of the two is in general not a solution. I would therefore not expect that (3),(4) behave similarly than (1),(2).

Comment: It's not general because there are lots of other solutions not of this form.  One expects the general solution of a PDE to depend on one or more arbitrary functions,  as opposed to an ODE where the general solution depends on arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Other solutions include $$u = a  \pm b^2 t +  b \sqrt{\sum_i (x_i - c_i)^2}$$ (for $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \ne (c_1, \ldots, c_n)$) and $$u = \pm \frac{b_1 x_1 + \ldots + b_n x_n + c}{4 (b_1^2 + \ldots + b_n^2) (t_0 - t)}$$ for $t \ne t_0$.

Comment: The intuition comes from looking for "separation of variables" solutions of forms such as $T(t) + X(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ or $T(t) X(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

Comment: Wow, thanks both of you. Looking at three example solutions that @RobertIsrael presented, every solution may behave differently, radically! So, it feels very challenging to propose "a general intuition" similar to the heat equation, then.

Alas, while it appears that I have learned such a basic property from you, maybe, is there anyone who can give me an example in the realworld described by equation (3)?